# Unity Android orientation change animation shows last orientation snapshot

Tags: java, c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

When orientation changes occur the unity player is notified in onConfigurationChanged() and this results in screen size and orientation changes in the unity Screen and ScreenOrientation classes. I have classes checking for these changes and then notifying a number of view classes to adjust layout. This process is not optimized and slower devices are not able to render the new layout in time for the Android OS freezing the screen and playing the rotation animation. If I'm going from landscape to portrait, I see a landscape snapshot shoved to the top half of the screen with the bottom half black. After the animation completes layout completes and things go to normal. I have identified this as a performance issue and there are certainly changes needed in that code.

However, my question is, can I adjust the time the Android OS takes before snapping a shot for the rotation animation? If not, can I change the way that rotation displays, for instance, stretch the snapshot to fill the screen at least? ( iOS seems to do this and it really helps visually )

Thank you!

Comment: Try those links [1](https://android.jlelse.eu/handling-orientation-changes-in-android-7072958c442a) and [2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes). I also heard that it's possible to use AsyncTask.